# Is their an official tool to tweak Windows 2008 server TCP configurations?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, tcp, tcpip

We are running scripts that initiates numerous TCP connections and disconnects right away. It's just to test if the remote report is opened and responsive.

But we are having random strange issues with our script so I'm suspecting that the windows server TCP configuration is ruining my script. But after searching, I didn't find an official source, tool to tweak\browse TCP configurations on the server.

We don't have staging\development servers, this is a production server and I need to be sure about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There most certainly is an official tool to tweak the TCP configuration in Windows Server 2008, it's called [Performance Tuning Guidelines for Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463394.aspx).

Page 11-17 digs into how performance tuning for the network subsystems in windows works, including improvements to TCP like window scaling.

The [Performance Tuning Guidelines for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463392.aspx) is updated to include new features in R2